# Do I need a third table in my schema

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

Scenario: Each **"order"** can only have one **"import file"** . So I created a table with its main columns as *order_code* and *file_code*  (Order_File Table)
Also Each **"order"** can have multiple **"Genes"** . So I created another table with its main columns as **order_code** and **gene_code**. ( Order_Gene table)

So now in front-end side, user picks an "order" from a combobox,  We show the import file of that order and the lists of genes for that order.

I wanted to know your opinion about this schema design and if I am designing it wrong or it is correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds right if I'm understanding you correctly. The import file is an attribute of an order, and the Genes table is on the many side of a one-to-many relationship allowing many genes to be associated with one order, but each gene can only be associated with one order.

If you want to associate many genes with many orders (i.e. 'reuse' records in the gene table for multiple orders) you'll need to create a 'link table' with an order_code and a gene_code column, and create a record there for each link or association between the two tables.

Comment: Paul, each Gene can belong to many orders too, for example Order1 can have Gene1 and Gene2  and then also Order2 can have Gene1 and Gene2 and Gene3 ... so now I need a Link Table?

Comment: Yes, in that case you'll need one to create the correct relationships: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Answer (score 1):

The design that you are talking about will work if each order code is unique.

Comment: what do you mean by being unique? we will have something like this: "Order1 has File1 and Gene 1 Gene2 Gene3 "  and also ""Order2 has File1 and Gene 1 Gene2 Gene4 Gene5 "